# May have a problem with variables being global /local? javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me which piece of code is not working as intended and an explanation as to why.

Trying to take any given two integers a and b, which can be positive or negative, find the sum of all the integers between and including them and return it. If the two numbers are equal return a or b.

Note: a and b are not ordered!

More can be found about the question in the link below.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/55f2b110f61eb01779000053/train/javascript

---

```
function getSum( a,b ){
  
   let count = 0;
     
    if(a>b){  
      let greaterNum = a;
      let lesserNum = b;
      count = lesserNum;
        for(lesserNum; lesserNum<greaterNum; lesserNum++){
        count += 1;
      }
       return count;
      
    }else if(a<b){
      let greaterNum = b; 
      let lesserNum = a;
      count = lesserNum;
      for(lesserNum; lesserNum<greaterNum; lesserNum++){
        count += 1;
      }
        return count;
    }else if (a==b){
      return a;
    }
  
    
  
  
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find the sum of all the integers between and including them and return it

You're doing:

```
count += 1;
```

ie, you're *counting* the number of numbers - not *summing* them.

You're also massively overcomplicating it:

```js
function getSum( a,b ){
   const start = Math.min(a,b);
   const end = Math.max(a,b);
   let sum = 0;
   for(let x = start;x<=end;x++)
      sum += x;
   return sum;  
}

console.log(getSum(0,10))
console.log(getSum(10,10))
console.log(getSum(-10,10))
console.log(getSum(10,-10))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks - I overlooked the count issue. Also the math.min/max was the function I needed!  Big help